# How stop HOOK node form submit

Tags: forms, database, nodes

My question is in the title, when i add a new element of entity "intervenant" I check, if there is already an intervenant with the name used in form_state, if the query returned me a result, i want to stop the insert into and be redirected in my front page.

I used `return FALSE;`

But it's didn't work.. You can see my code :

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'intervenant')
    ->fieldCondition('field_int_projett', 'target_id', $idProject, '=')
    ->fieldCondition('field_int_numero_lot', 'value', $lot, '=')
    ->fieldCondition('field_int_intervenants', 'target_id', $intervenant_id, '=')
    ->propertyCondition('status', 1);
$intervenant_externe_pjt = $query->execute();

if(!empty($intervenant_externe_pjt['node'])) {
    return FALSE;
}
```

How can i stop the submit, if it's possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stopping a submit is best done in a validation function. You need to have this code in a custom validation handler that you add to the form, and then you set a validation error on it.

[Learn how to add custom validation to an existing Drupal form](http://befused.com/drupal/form-validation)

Redirecting on form validation fail seems to be a problem. Look here for workaround:

[Redirect form in validation fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104233/redirect-form-in-validation-fail)

As to hook_node_submit, the docs have this to say:

> Act on a node after validated form values have been copied to it.
>
> This hook is invoked when a node form is submitted with either the
>   "Save" or "Preview" button, after form values have been copied to the
>   form state's node object, but before the node is saved or previewed.
>   It is a chance for modules to adjust the node's properties from what
>   they are simply after a copy from $form_state['values']. This hook is
>   intended for adjusting non-field-related properties. See
>   hook_field_attach_submit() for customizing field-related properties.

This hook is not a good place to try and stop submission, as form validation has already passed. It is therefore assumed that the node should be saved to the db.

Comment: Hum ok, i found hook_validate executed before the hook submit as you said, i can use set_error to stop my submit. I will try this.

Comment: Ok it's working with the Hook_node_validate ! But now i have a problem when i want to delete my node :D because the delete button works with validate too.

Comment: $form_state should have the button that was clicked in there. Try with $form_state['clicked_button']['#value']. Or place the validation handler on the button itself. Look [here](http://alvinalexander.com/drupal/drupal-form-submit-button-handler-function) and replace submit with validate

Comment: @Remi inspect triggering element in form state and only set error if it's save button, simple as this. If you have problems with that part, please ask another question :)